# Creating a car engine sound 

Tags: design, engine, synthesis, car

I need to create a somewhat cartoony sound of a small vehicle (truck) engine idling, speeding up, and coming to an abrupt stop. Short of recording a vehicle, is there any way I can synthesize a basic motor sound/loop? It doesn't have to be incredibly realistic, more like something you would hear in Mario Kart. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Try this out:

[youtube]m40ZAfJb4f8[/youtube]